# jquery how to change class of parent div on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass, toggleclass

When I slideToggle the simple accordian that I have, I would like to change the class of the link element and the **.revealBox** div  that wraps the whole accordion depending on whether the accordion is opened or closed

my jquery is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // choose text for the show/hide link - can contain HTML (e.g. an image)
    var showText = 'Hide Information';
    var hideText = 'Show Information';
    var is_visible = false;
    $('.collapseLink').append('<span class="dottedBot">' + showText + '</span>');
    $('.revealBoxContents').show();
    $('a.collapseLink').click(function() {
        // switch visibility
        is_visible = !is_visible;
        // change the link depending on whether the element is shown or hidden
        $(this).html((!is_visible) ? showText : hideText);
        // toggle the display - uncomment the next line for a basic "accordion" style
        //$('.toggle').hide();$('a.toggleLink').html(showText);
        $(this).parent().next('.revealBoxContents').slideToggle('slow');
        // return false so any link destination is not followed
        return false;
    });
    // toggle the bottom link
    $('.collapseLink').click(function() {
        $(this).parents('.revealBoxContents').stop(true, true).slideToggle('slow');
        $(".collapseLink").html((!is_visible) ? showText : hideText);
        $(this).parent('.item').toggleClass('current');

    });
});
```

my Url is

http://satbulsara.com/NSJ-local/eqs1.htm

Thanks,

Sat

Comment: And what is problem? It seems you are already changing classes...

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the addClass() function on the element.

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

You can also do that using toggleClass() as seen on jQuery documentation :

```
$('div.foo').toggleClass(function() {
      if ($(this).parent().is('.bar')) {
        return 'happy';
      } else {
        return 'sad';
      }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: how would i implement this? as when i open and close toggle it keeps the same class

Comment: also how would i change the class of another div

Comment: To implement that on another div you need to change the "div.foo" with the correct selector something like $('#divID').toggleClass(). If you want the div to keep the class it already has then use addClass like this : $('#divID').addClass('TheNewClass').

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of jquery's [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) to add and remove classes .